# Openssl return status in cmd

Tags: php, apache, openssl, cmd, exec

I am using openssl command for creating certificate using PHP.I am using exec.When I give exec the command ,the return status is `1`,I echoed whatever i insert in `exec(OpenSSL statement)` and try it through cmd and it works fine (generate certificates) but it doesn't work when I run it through PHP exec. Anyone who can help me for this.
Thanks

Comment: Figure out which user the PHP exec is running under and make sure that account has the appropriate permission(s).

Comment: @ethrbunny I am using as localhost, and I have the permissions..

Comment: localhost = server or username? PHP may be running as the apache account.

Comment: @ethrbunny localhost is the sername

Comment: Can you run any commands? 'ls'? try 'whoami' and look at the result.

Comment: @ethrbunny when I did whoami it displayed me "nt authority\system"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21901/discussion-between-ethrbunny-and-user1765876)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd have an easier time with [phpseclib, a pure PHP X.509 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)? Example of how to create a self-signed cert:

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

// create private key / x.509 cert for stunnel / website
$privKey = new Crypt_RSA();
extract($privKey->createKey());
$privKey->loadKey($privatekey);

$pubKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$pubKey->loadKey($publickey);
$pubKey->setPublicKey();

$subject = new File_X509();
$subject->setDNProp('id-at-organizationName', 'phpseclib demo cert');
//$subject->removeDNProp('id-at-organizationName');
$subject->setPublicKey($pubKey);

$issuer = new File_X509();
$issuer->setPrivateKey($privKey);
$issuer->setDN($subject->getDN());

$x509 = new File_X509();
//$x509->setStartDate('-1 month'); // default: now
//$x509->setEndDate('+1 year'); // default: +1 year

$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $subject);
echo "the stunnel.pem contents are as follows:\r\n\r\n";
echo $privKey->getPrivateKey();
echo "\r\n";
echo $x509->saveX509($result);
echo "\r\n";
?>
```